# 1993 Dodge Stealth Clutch Pedal Flat On The Floor

Tags: clutch, dodge

I have a 1993 Dodge Stealth that had not been driven for the past 4 years.  Recently I have the need for the car and was trying to get it running.  I was able to start the engine (got a new battery) but discover the clutch pedal once stepped down, would just stay flat on the floor and not come back up.  I can pull it all the way up by hand and it'll stay up but if I step it down, it'll sink down and stay on the floor again.  Where should I start?  Checking the clutch reservoir and fill if it's low or empty?

Answer (score 1):

The Stealth uses an hydraulic slave cylinder to control the clutch. If you look on the firewall of the engine compartment you should see a resevoir similar to the brake mastercylinder. The system has two main componenets the resevoir and the slave cylinder. A leaking slave cylinder is the more common failure item. You can try refilling the resevoir and bleeding it. The bleeding technique is similar to bleeding brakes. This will only be a temporary fix as the leak is still present.

Comment: Thanks for the info mikes.  I have located the reservoir but was unable to open the cap.  It is a screw on or a cork-like cap?

Comment: The images I've seen online appear to be a twist cap. From the images it looks to be a 1/4 turn to disengage the hooks then lift up.